# Visual C++ 2010 Express: extension SDK available?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, vsx, visual-c++-2010

Allegedly, Visual C++ 2010 Express, unlike previous versions, supports third party extensions.  I just downloaded the release candidate SDK for Visual Studio 2010, but the installer fails saying that I don't have Visual Studio installed (which is true since i use Visual C++ 2010 Express). Have I missed something? Is there a version of the extension SDK that works with Express?

Comment: None of the express editions support third party extensions.

Comment: There may be a difference between what the express editions allow and what the extensions allow. Also, the SDK isn't a third party extension. A pure guess - maybe they don't want to be sorting out unsuppported-in-express issues from the bug reports.

Comment: Where did the "allegation" of third party extension support come from?

Answer (score 2):

Visual C++ 2010 Express (or any of the Express versions for that matter) are **NOT** extensible.

The Visual Studio 2010 SDK can only be used with Professional or higher (as stated in the requirements on [the download page](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=47305cf4-2bea-43c0-91cd-1b853602dcc5&displaylang=en)).

You haven't missed anything, but your source of information was incorrect.

Comment: Actually, Visual Studio 2010 Express allows some extensions. Have a look at the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7940249/restrictions-on-installing-extensions-or-add-ins-in-visual-studio-2010-express